# Azure ARM - Create SQL Database from Azure GUI - privateEndpointNestedTemplateId and privateEndpointDnsRecordUniqueId seem like similar GUIDs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have been using Azure GUI to create a new database for our Dev environment. To enable automation I used their function "Download a template for automation".

[image]

This works out of the box but when creating a new parameters file to match production I noticed something for `privateEndpointNestedTemplateId` and `privateEndpointDnsRecordUniqueId`.

`privateEndpointNestedTemplateId` looked like this:

```
pe-12345678-f5cd-4868-8705-4bbd9879b016
```

`privateEndpointDnsRecordUniqueId` looked like this:

```
12345678-f5cd-4868-8705-4bbd9879b019
```

The only difference between the two are three numeric values for the last character.

Tried creating a new template and the same thing happened.

```
pe-12345678-2d1c-4273-9544-6a5b5f061013

12345678-2d1c-4273-9544-6a5b5f061016
```

Does Azure require these Guids to be related and match a specific pattern or can I generate a new GUID separately for them? Tried looking for documentation about this but I did not find any.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a ***SQL DB with a new Private endpoint***, You must have noticed that there are couple of other deployments performed by azure for resources like ***`Subnet Policies , Private Endpoint, Private DNS Record`*** which is triggered because you are creating ***Private endpoint*** and every nested deployment will have ***Private endpoint Nested Template ID*** joined by their names . Then there will be nested deployments for ***Private DNS*** like ***`Endpoint DNS Records , NIC DNS Records and DNS Records`*** which will have the ***Private DNS Unique ID*** joined to their names.

[image]

> Does Azure require these Guids to be related and match a specific
> pattern or can I generate a new GUID separately for them? Tried
> looking for documentation about this but I did not find any.

They are just the ***Template GUID's*** which are being used for ***Nested Deployment Names*** . So ,it won't create any problem if you generate them separately. Azure will by default generate the GUID's for the azure resources  which we cannot change or assign. As Azure is generating those nested template Id's while we are downloading the main template , I guess for convenience it keeps the GUID's almost same .

**I tested the same using different GUID for them and the outputs are as below:**

[image]

[image]